# I use UTF-16LE when I parsing xml. But, it does not work on some device

Tags: java-me, utf-16, utf, series-40, nokia-s40

Device is getting a UTF16 encoded XML response then I parse xml.
On some device it doesn't work. All these devices support utf-16.
What may be the problem in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's tricky without seeing code, but if I remember correctly, some nokia devices were choosy about whether you used a hyphen or not in the encoding name. If "UTF16" doesn't work, try "UTF-16" instead, or vise versa.